# DNN: settings and edit buttons not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I created a module with Christoc's Template for `DNN 7.0` and it works fine on my local `DNN 7.0.6` instance.

I uploaded the module to the server (using the extension wizard) and placed the module on a page. Everything seems fine, until I try to edit or use settings. Both buttons are missing for my module and it also affects neighbour modules on the page.

The server DNN version is: 7.0 Pro.
The module works fine, but I don't get those two buttons while on edit mode.
Does anybody know why this could be happening and/or how to solve it?

---

Edit: So, i found the issue, it seems like DNN 7.0.6 Pro ver. has some sort of bug with culture information. The bug was caused by adding the following:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-VE");

I already contacted Dnn to let them know about this.
Hope this helps somebody out there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found the issue, it seems like DNN 7.0.6 Pro ver. has some sort of bug with culture information. The bug was caused by adding the following: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-VE");

I already contacted Dnn to let them know about this. Hope this helps somebody out there!